# How to get JSON object without converting in Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, json, rest

I need download json object from REST server without converting by GSON. But not understand how make in Retrofit 2.0 bata 1

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Shan Xeeshi see my solution below

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `JsonElement` as your pojo. For example

In your FlowerApi interafce:

```
    @GET("/flower")
    Call<JsonElement> getFlowers();
```

In your main class:

```
    Call<JsonElement> getFlowersCall = httpApiClass.getFlowers();

    getFlowersCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JsonElement> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, jsonElement.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Actually, the response is still converted to `JsonElement` by the Gson converter, but you can get something that is close to the raw response.

Answer (score 1):

1   `compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'`

2  `OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
     // client.interceptors().add(new UrlInterceptor());
        client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());
        AppApi api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
                        // add a converter for String
                .addConverter(String.class, new ToStringConverter())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
                .create(AppApi.class);`

Comment: Can you please explain ToStringConverter() ?

Answer (score 1):

We can get **JsonObject (com.google.gson)** and parse this as well as standard **JSONObject (org.json)**

*Interface FlowerApi*

```
@GET("/flower")
Call<JsonObject> getFlowers();
```

*In rest handler use*

```
FlowerApi api = ApiFactory.createRetrofitService(FlowerApi.class);
Call<JsonObject> call = api.getFlowers();
retrofit.Response response = call.execute();
if (response.isSuccess()) {
   JsonObject object = (JsonObject) response.body();
}
```

*Api Factory class help a create retrofit service easy*

```
public class ApiFactory {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 60;
    private static final int WRITE_TIMEOUT = 120;
    private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10;

    private static final OkHttpClient CLIENT = new OkHttpClient();

    private static final String BASE_URL = "flowers.com";

    static {
        CLIENT.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        CLIENT.setWriteTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        CLIENT.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @NonNull
    public static <S> S createRetrofitService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return getRetrofit().create(serviceClass);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(CLIENT)
                .build();
    }
}
```

*In build.gradle*

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
```