# Get JSONObject from Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit and want to get a simple JSONObject returned.  Not an object model... an actual JSONObject object.

I've tried using `Call<JSONObject>` and `Call<ResponseBody>` with no luck.  Responses are successful but body is empty.  I've confirmed the response in postman is NOT empty.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Try `JsonObject` instead of `JSONObject`

Comment: @epicpandaforce I would LOVE to... can't though

Comment: I guess you can use something like the code in https://github.com/sebastien-roch/retrofit2-jsonobject-converter/tree/a7d86196a9543f23b881a95738536381d0752ff2

Comment: _Why_ do you want a JSONObject instead of a nice custom object?

Comment: @Benp. the server endpoint can return 1 of 2 possible json objects.  It's poorly designed and the backend team is taking forever to take care of it.  so I need to get the json then check the contents before parsing

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32963519/9867072

Comment: What about using `Call<String>` and constructing a `new JSONObject` from the fetch text?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to check the content of the response before parsing, you can use JsonDeserializer along with Gson library. If you don't have Gson implemented yet, add this to your app level gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

In your code:

```
public Retrofit provideRetrofit() {

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ParsedObject.class, new MyDeserializer()).create();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();
}
```

**ParsedObject.class**

```
public abstract class ParsedObject {
    public static final int RESPONSE_TYPE_1 = 1;
    public static final int RESPONSE_TYPE_2 = 2;

    abstract public int getResponseType();
}
```

These are for your parsed objects. Since you have 2 types of responses, You can create 2 saperate classes depends on the response type which inherites `ParsedObject.class`.

**TypeOneResponse.class**

```
public class TypeOneResponse extends ParsedObject {
    // fields, constructors, getters/setters..

    @Overried
    public int getResponseType() {
       return RESPONSE_TYPE_1;    
    }
}
```

you can do the same thing for your TypeTwoResponse.class but returning RESPONSE_TYPE_2 for the getResponseType() method.

**MyDeserializer.class**

```
public class CurrentPriceDeserializer implements MyDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

         // Now, check the Json respons using the raw json (JsonElement) parameter. 
         // Determine if it is type 1 or 2. 
         boolean isTypeOne = checkResponseType()

        // Deserialize or manually parse objects... 

        return isTypeOne ? resultTypeOne : resultTypeTwo;
       }
}
```

And finally, in your Retrofit callback

```
ParsedObject result = deserializedResult;
if (result.getResponseType() == RESPONSE_TYPE_1) {
    // cast the object to TypeOneResponse or use it accordingly...      
} else {
    // case the object to TypeTwoResponse or use it accordingly...
}
```